# Vue Pug Computed Property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pug

Trying to get pug integrated into an existing Vue3 project. After installing pug and pug-plain-loader, the variables from my computed properties no longer work.

Old Code (no pug, works):

```html
<template>
  <h1>
    {{ name }}
  </h1>
</template>
```

New Code (with pug, doesn't work):

```html
<template lang="pug">
  h1
    {{ name }}
</template>
```

The error I get reads:

```
...unexpected text "{{ na"
    at makeError...
```

---

Am I missing something else that needs to happen to get pug up and running in my Vue3 application? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bringing the `h1` to the left and having the interpolate on the same line should fix the issue.

```html
<template lang="pug">
h1 {{ name }}
</template>
```